# How do I transfer a normal binary tree into a "smarter" binary tree where each node knows its parents, total subnodes and level?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, language-agnostic, nodes

I'm still getting used to data structures, and I'm comfortable with traversing binary trees in the various ways, but I'm presented now with a situation where I have a normal binary tree, constructed of nodes that only know have `data`, `left` and `right` attributes.

However I want to transfer it into a "smarter" binary tree. This tree is to know its parent node, its total subnodes, and the level in the total tree it is at.

I'm really struggling with how I'd go about transferring the one "dumber" tree into the smarter version. My first instinct is to traverse recursively, but I'm not sure how I'd then be able to distinguish the parent and the level.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the old tree to a new tree, using the normal recursive methods to traverse the original.

Since you're adding new attributes to the nodes, I presume you'll need to construct new nodes with fields for the new attributes.

Define a recursive function to copy the (sub)tree rooted at a given node. It needs as input its depth and parent. (The parent, of course, needs to be what will be its parent in the new tree.) Let it return the root of the new (sub)tree.

```
function copy_node (old_node, new_parent, depth) -> returns new_node {
    new_node = new node
    new_node.data = old_root.data // whatever that data might be
    new_node.depth = depth
    new_node.parent = parent
    new_node.left = copy_node (old_node.left, new_node, depth + 1)
    new_node.right = copy_node (old_node.right, new_node, depth + 1)
    return new_node }
```

Copy the whole tree with

```
new_tree = copy_node (old_tree, nil, 0)
```

If you're using a language where fields can be added to existing objects willy-nilly, you don't even have to do the extra copying:

```
function adorn_node (node, parent, depth) {
    node.parent = parent
    node.depth = depth
    adorn_node (node.left, node, depth + 1)
    adorn_node (node.right, node, depth + 1) }
```

and start the ball rolling with

```
adorn_node (root, nil, 0)
```

That having been said, you will probably discover that there is a very good reason why most binary tree implementations do not contain these extra fields. It's a lot of work to maintain them across the many different operations you want to perform on trees. *depth*, especially, is hard to keep correct when you need to re-balance a tree.

And the fields don't generally buy you anything. Most algorithms that operate on trees do so using recursive functions, and as you can see from the above examples it's really easy to re-calculate both *parent* and *depth* on the fly while you're walking the tree. They don't need to be stored in the nodes themselves.

Tree-balancing often needs to know the difference in heights of the left and right subtrees. ("depth" is the distance to the root; "height" is the distance to the most distant leaf node in the subtree.) *height* is not so easy to calculate on the way down from the root, but fortunately you're usually only interested in which of the subtrees has the greatest *height*, and for that it's usually sufficient to store only the values -1, 0, +1 in each node.